# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator v6.1.1 make lock file while moving a file using VFS

Tags: wso2, vfs, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am using **WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.1.1 .** I am using VFS to poll a file from one directory and move to another directory. But my proxy service is making a lock file, and unable to move the file. I initially thought that it is a file permission issue but when I try it with Inbound Endpoint or my custom java mediator called in a proxy service. Then file is successfully moved.

**Lock File:**

[image]

**Proxy Service Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="TestCSVFileMoving"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="vfs">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"
              separator=",========----------Test CSV File Proxy Triggered------======="/>
      </inSequence>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">true</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">30</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:file:///files/uploads</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">vfs:file:///opt/file/con/Fail</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">Test.*.csv</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">vfs:file:///opt/file/con/Out</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

**Error Logs:**

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-10 12:51:56,634] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener} -  File object 'file:///files/uploads/Test.csv'cloud not be moved, will remain in "locked" state {org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error moving file : file:///files/uploads/Test.csv to file:///opt/file/con/Out
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.handleException(AbstractTransportListener.java:343)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.moveOrDeleteAfterProcessing(VFSTransportListener.java:682)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.scanFileOrDirectory(VFSTransportListener.java:499)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:188)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:134)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not rename "file:///files/uploads/Test.csv" because it is read-only.
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.moveTo(AbstractFileObject.java:1087)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.moveOrDeleteAfterProcessing(VFSTransportListener.java:680)
    ... 8 more
```

**Problem Statement:**

My Question is that in the error log, it clearly states that it is a read only file. But Why that by using Inbound Endpoint and Calling a custom mediator I am able to move the file.But using VFS only I am getting this error? Also is there any way to solve it. If I have to use the VFS.